# Do they mean the same thing?

Tags: grammar

- No purity of spirit is enough to send you to heaven.
- No matter how pure you may be, that won't guarantee your ticket to heaven.

Comment: The first is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, yes these mean roughly the same.

As you can probably see, the first example leaves a little wiggle-room, in that it is only talking about "purity of spirit" whereas the second example is talking about the person as a whole, but since one's spirit is a vague concept anyway, it is hard to see any significant difference in meaning.